# what is the correct way to include a script in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I am currently working on a project using Django, and I am having a weird problem with my script tags. 
I have a layout.html file in which I have included Jquery and Bootstrap in the head. Using jinja, I am extending layout.html for my new file, main.html. In my new file I am now including a new script because this script is peculiar to this page.

The problem I am having is that this new script does not work in main.html unless I again include Jquery in inside main.html. Please, I would like to know if there is an explanation for this? or maybe I am missing something?

```
layout.html file

<html> 
   <head>
    // script to include jquery here, version 3.3.1
    // other scripts include, bootstrap.js, popper.js, knockout.js
   </head>
   <body>
     { block content % } 

     { % endblock % }
 </body>
</html>
```

Sample of main.html

```
main.html

{ % extends "layout.html" %} {% block content %}

   // This new script below only works if jquery is included here 
   // new script here 

 <div> </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I am also using knockout.js, from which I am calling functions in new script on document load. The new script requires Jquery, But I don't understand why it's not finding the jquery unless its included in the same file. The I also get and error when I include JS in the main.html file because jquery should be included before bootstrap.js.

Please, I would be happy if anyone has encountered similar problems or if anyone can explain this to me.

This is the head for layout.html:

```
<head>
    <title>Suggesto</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <!-- font awesome-->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css"
    />

    <!-- Js-cookie-->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2/src/js.cookie.min.js"></script>


    <!--Jquery-->
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <!-- Popper.js-->
    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap.js-->
    <script src="/static/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

    <!-- Font -->
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Serif+SC|Open+Sans|Quicksand|Montserrat"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <!--Knockout.js-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

    {% load staticfiles %}

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="/static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"
      type="text/css"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/mainpage.css" type="text/css" />
  </head>
```

The main.html starts like this

```
{%extends "mainpage/layout.html" %} {% block content %}
<script src="/static/js/jquery.session.js"></script>
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="/static/css/star-rating.min.css"
  media="all"
  type="text/css"
/>

<script src="/static/js/star-rating.min.js"></script>

<script src="/static/js/suggest.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/suggest.css" type="text/css" />
<!-- Start -->
<div class="container" id="Page">
```

Comment: Please show us the <head> for *layout.html* so we can see how you include jQuery.

Comment: Hello, I just added the head

Comment: Yes, it looks as expected. All files are included when I inspect. the script which am trying to get to work is the star-rating.min.js

Comment: So then you need to look more into the specific error you're getting from star-rating.min.js because it's definitely not an issue that jquery isn't loaded. it looks more like a javascript issue than a django issue.

Comment: the star-rating just doesnt do anything, but if I include the jquery right above it ( in the main.html file), its starts working. Thats why I think its something that has to do with the order in which the files are being included

Comment: that still doesn't make sense. open your debugger, set a breakpoint in your star-rating script (instead of min use the full version) and start looking into why nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being a function from Knockoutjs:

```
ko.cleanNode( )
```

I don't know what this function does under the hood, something to look at. Feel free to provide more details if you know more.